# TinyMCE - how do I reliably get the node that was selected prior to the blur event?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm trying to delete an empty/hanging list item if the user focuses outside the editor when there's one remaining (eg if the user leaves the cursor inside the `li` and clicks outside the editor,

1. This is my list item
2. This is my other list item.
3. 

... the "3." list item should be removed)

I have written an eventhandler for the onBlur event, which fires fine.  It checks `tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getNode()` to see if it was an `li` node, and if it doesn't contain anything then it is removed.

This works nicely in my isolated testing environment but when used in the actual application, `tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getNode()` is returning a different node (actually one OUTSIDE the editor altogether) and I can't for the life of me figure out why.  Perhaps something inside TinyMCE is changing the "active node" before my onBlur event handler is triggering, or something similar.

Does anybody have any ideas/suggestions?  I'm really stumped.

Comment: don't use tinymce.activeEditor. use tinymce.get('your_editor_id') instead

Comment: Unfortunately, this is being used in an app that requires multiple editable divs on the page at once :(  TinyMCE config uses `selector: div.editable`

Comment: this is no problem, as long as each div has its unique id (this is your editor id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that getNode() gets the parent node.  you have to search through the children.
I found that getContent gave me the information about the node I selected (a href)

I did find somewhere this search code but I have to work out how I will be able to confirm which child is selected.

```
myParentNode = ed.selection.getNode();
if (myParentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'a')
{
     ed.dom.remove(myParentNode);
 }
 else
 {
      var child = myParentNode.firstChild;

      while (child)
      {
           if (child.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'a')
           {
                ed.dom.remove(child);
            }
            child = child.nextSibling;
       }

}
```